TypeError (is not iterable) when adding SVG to FabricJS canvas
I have a fabricjs canvas, and I'm trying to add an SVG to it. But whatever I do, I get problems. It keeps saying:
"Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t is not iterable".
let svg = `<svg viewBox="-8 -8 136 136">
<path stroke="#000000" stroke-width="8" d="m0 51.82677l0 0c0 -28.623135 23.203636 -51.82677 51.82677 -51.82677l0 0c13.745312 0 26.927654 5.4603047 36.64706 15.17971c9.719406 9.719404 15.17971 22.901749 15.17971 36.64706l0 0c0 28.623135 -23.203636 51.82677 -51.82677 51.82677l0 0c-28.623135 0 -51.82677 -23.203636 -51.82677 -51.82677zm25.913385 0l0 0c0 14.311565 11.60182 25.913387 25.913385 25.913387c14.311565 0 25.913387 -11.601822 25.913387 -25.913387c0 -14.311565 -11.601822 -25.913385 -25.913387 -25.913385l0 0c-14.311565 0 -25.913385 11.60182 -25.913385 25.913385z" fill="none"></path>
</svg>`;

let canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
let path = fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg, function(objects, options) {
    let obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    
    obj.set({
        left: canvas.width / 2 - obj.width / 2,
        top: canvas.height / 2 - obj.height / 2
    });
    canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
});

Hopefully someone can help me out

I've added an answer as a starting point. I suspect there's more to the story...

For Fabric > 6.0.0 use this:
  fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg).then((result) => {
    canvas.add(...(result.objects.filter((obj) => !!obj)))renderAll();
  });


This seems to be working! It's just a bummer that Fabric documentation is so limited, even their official examples are using the old implementation. Do you have by any chance have an example of how it works with an SVG group?

@Jordy, according to the source code SVGGroup is just a regular fabric Group.

For anyone with the same issue, I got it working now with the following:
    fabric.loadSVGFromURL(mySvg).then((results) => {
        const svgGroup = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(results.objects, results.options);
        canvas.add(svgGroup);

});

I'm not sure which version you are using, but I've added your code to a runnable snippet and it seems to work fine for me:
1.7.6:


let svg = `<svg viewBox="-8 -8 136 136">
<path stroke="#000000" stroke-width="8" d="m0 51.82677l0 0c0 -28.623135 23.203636 -51.82677 51.82677 -51.82677l0 0c13.745312 0 26.927654 5.4603047 36.64706 15.17971c9.719406 9.719404 15.17971 22.901749 15.17971 36.64706l0 0c0 28.623135 -23.203636 51.82677 -51.82677 51.82677l0 0c-28.623135 0 -51.82677 -23.203636 -51.82677 -51.82677zm25.913385 0l0 0c0 14.311565 11.60182 25.913387 25.913385 25.913387c14.311565 0 25.913387 -11.601822 25.913387 -25.913387c0 -14.311565 -11.601822 -25.913385 -25.913387 -25.913385l0 0c-14.311565 0 -25.913385 11.60182 -25.913385 25.913385z" fill="none"></path>
</svg>`;

let canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
let path = fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg, function(objects, options) {
  let obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

  obj.set({
    left: canvas.width / 2 - obj.width / 2,
    top: canvas.height / 2 - obj.height / 2
  });
  canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
});
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.6/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas><br/>



5.3.1:


let svg = `<svg viewBox="-8 -8 136 136">
<path stroke="#000000" stroke-width="8" d="m0 51.82677l0 0c0 -28.623135 23.203636 -51.82677 51.82677 -51.82677l0 0c13.745312 0 26.927654 5.4603047 36.64706 15.17971c9.719406 9.719404 15.17971 22.901749 15.17971 36.64706l0 0c0 28.623135 -23.203636 51.82677 -51.82677 51.82677l0 0c-28.623135 0 -51.82677 -23.203636 -51.82677 -51.82677zm25.913385 0l0 0c0 14.311565 11.60182 25.913387 25.913385 25.913387c14.311565 0 25.913387 -11.601822 25.913387 -25.913387c0 -14.311565 -11.601822 -25.913385 -25.913387 -25.913385l0 0c-14.311565 0 -25.913385 11.60182 -25.913385 25.913385z" fill="none"></path>
</svg>`;

let canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
let path = fabric.loadSVGFromString(svg, function(objects, options) {
  let obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

  obj.set({
    left: canvas.width / 2 - obj.width / 2,
    top: canvas.height / 2 - obj.height / 2
  });
  canvas.add(obj).renderAll();
});
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/5.3.1/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"></canvas><br/>




Thanks for the help. I think both your examples have the same code :) Seems like they changed implementation as of Fabric 6?

@Jordy It would have been better to explain which version you were using in your question ;-)

Yes you're right, apologies, and appreciate the help!
